# Git cannot find ssh-keys in windows console

Tags: git, msysgit

I have a git repository and I can successfully clone it in my Windows machine and Bash-console. But when I am trying to clone it in windows console git cannot find ssh-keys and ask my password.

Here is some usefull information:

```
[36]: ssh -v -T xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '62.105.139.252' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

$HOMW:

```
[43]: echo $HOME 
C:\Users\myname
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do `cd ~; pwd -W` then your bash keys are in the .ssh subdirectory of this folder. pwd -W gives the Windows path of the msys directory you are in. Presumably in your case this is not the same as HOME or USERPROFILE or HOMEPATH in your cmd prompt shell. You can use the HOME environment variable to ensure they both match up. If you don't have HOME set in the Windows environment then it gets set to %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% if those are set or %USERPROFILE% (depends if you are on an NT domain or not I believe). If you set HOME yourself, then that will override any autodetection.

Comment: @demas, in other words, that sole `/` separator in front of the `.ssh` directory is wrong as `.ssh` is supposed to be located under your "home directory", and so the whole thing should have looked like `~/.ssh` or `/C/Users/demas/.ssh` or something alike matching your system. That's where the Pat's explanation starts.